# Sitecore media publishing to file system when not configured to do so

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I have a SiteCore instance where the web.config values for media are as follows:

```
<setting name="Media.DisableFileMedia" value="false" />
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false" />
<setting name="Media.FileFolder" value="/App_Data/MediaFiles" />
<setting name="Media.UseItemPaths" value="true" />
```

So, this should mean that the item will be stored in the database and not the file system, correct?  I ask because they are being stored on the file system, with a path that looks like this:

/App_Data/Replicated/MediaFiles/6/4/E/{64EC628B-9C94-4416-B9BD-5A90EA7D8971}220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg

Does anyone know why that would be?  This is a small part of a larger puzzle I'm trying to understand.

Comment: What does `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` show? Also, it's possible to have a mixture of file and database media.. can you confirm that NEW uploads are getting stored as files?

Comment: All of the values are the same, save this one: Media.FileFolder is set to /App_Data/Replicated/MediaFiles, which is different that the value in the web.config. That makes the path that the image uses slightly less mysterious.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that users can manually specify whether a file should be uploaded as files on the filesystem. I discovered that content editors on a site I have been developing were doing so out of habit based on past sites they had worked on. To prevent users from having this choice, you may set the Upload.UserSelectableDestination setting to false (default is true).

Answer (score 0):

**Media.DisableFileMedia** is more to turn on or off the option of either storing the media item in SC or on the file system (in the actual SC UI)

**Media.UploadAsFiles** is used to indicate whether the media items are put in SC (if false) or on the file system (if true) - If you have DisableFileMedia set to true, then this is ignored and considered to be "true"

**Media.FileFolder** is obviously the location of where to put the files on the file system, should any the above be set to true.

**Media.UseItemPaths** actually has nothing to do with storing media items on the file system. It simply is a toggle between showing URLs like "~/media/[item id]" vs the full path of the media item.

Comment: Okay....so given the values above, UploadAsFiles is false, which means it would NOT be storing files on the drive, but this is overrriden by DisableFileMedia, which is false, meaning that it WOULD be storing files on the drive?  That's the only scenario I can see that would make sense, although that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Yeah.....when I look at my configuration...stated above...it tells me that the site *shouldn't* be storing data on the drive.  But it is.  Any ideas why would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. After the 5 hours of investigation, i found that **App_config\Include\ScalabilitySettings.config** overrides the **Media.FileFolder** value. So disable the **ScalabilitySettings.config** and try again.  It will store all file in the folder which was specified by the **Media.FileFolder** setting.

Answer for solving the problem:
disable  **App_config\Include\ScalabilitySettings.config** or **change value of Media.FileFolder** in this config